# How to remove Dropbox

Tags: debian, package-management, dpkg, dropbox

I am trying to remove Dropbox from my computer.  So far I have done the following:

```
sudo aptitude remove dropbox
sudo aptitude purge dropbox
```

But this didn't get rid of it 100%

```
oshiro@debian:~$ locate dropbox
/usr/share/nmap/scripts/broadcast-dropbox-listener.nse
/var/cache/apt/archives/dropbox_1.6.1_i386.deb
/var/lib/apt/lists/linux.dropbox.com_debian_dists_wheezy_Release
/var/lib/apt/lists/linux.dropbox.com_debian_dists_wheezy_Release.gpg
/var/lib/apt/lists/linux.dropbox.com_debian_dists_wheezy_main_binary-i386_Packages
oshiro@debian:~$
```

I know I can delete each of those manually, but wanted to know if that is the correct way of removing a .deb installed application?

Comment: I am also interested to know this. I keep getting `gnome-session[1831]: WARNING: Could not parse desktop file dropbox.desktop or it references a not found TryExec binary` after uninstalling it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have already completely removed Dropbox from your computer, at least in ways that manifest themselves by a file whose name contains `dropbox`. You may have other traces of your use of Dropbox remaining, for example in your browser history. When it comes to file names, check `Dropbox` as well (`locate -i dropbox` will do it).

None of the files you list are caused by even a partial installation of Dropbox.

- `/usr/share/nmap/scripts/broadcast-dropbox-listener.nse` is part of [nmap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nmap). It's the component that allows nmap to recognize a Dropbox server on the machine that it's scanning. It is completely unrelated to your use of Dropbox.
- `/var/cache/apt/archives/dropbox_1.6.1_i386.deb` is the Debian package file for Dropbox. It is in the cache of downloaded package files. You can remove it manually or call `apt-get clean` (or the corresponding command in another APT frontend) to empty the cache.
- The files in `/var/lib/apt/lists` are available package sources from `linux.dropbox.com`. These lists are updated by `apt-get update` (or the corresponding command in another APT frontend). To get rid of this file (which you don't need any more if you aren't going to reinstall Dropbox), edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` or a file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` and remove the line(s) that mention `linux.dropbox.com`, then run `apt-get update`.

Answer (score 3):

In my experience the `.deb` in /var/cache/apt/archives should be removed by the `sudo aptitude purge dropbox`, but maybe that did not happen because you already had done the `remove` first.

You should first try:

```
sudo aptitude autoclean
```

and if there are any file left after that use:

```
dpkg -S /full/path/to/file
```

if they belong to some other package, or are things that are residues from installing/using dropbox.